# Why doesn't sudo crontab work but crontab works?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, ruby

I want to execute a ruby script containing sudo commands. If I enter this command in " crontab -e ", it works fine:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ruby ~/myfolder/test.rb >> ~/myfolder/mylog.log 2>&1
```

Since my script contains sudo commands, I used "sudo crontab -e" and wrote:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ruby home/USERNAME/myfolder/test.rb >> home/USERNAME/myfolder/mylog.log 2>&1
```

But, it doesn't work. The log file isn't created in the second case. I used have a different address too.

Comment: `home/USERNAME` is a *relative* path - you likely need `/home/USERNAME`

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for very helpful cron output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I enter this command in " crontab -e ", it works fine:

That one is executed as you user so understands your HOME.

> Since my script contains sudo commands, I used "sudo crontab -e" and wrote:

Problem: if your line `home/USERNAME/` should be `/home/USERNAME/` (twice!) where USERNAME needs to be your actual user. You need an absolute PATH in crontab.

And indeed: the error is likely logged to /var/log/syslog

Oh and please do no use * * * * * without having some logic inside your script to have it not execute more times then you really want. If you need to run it forever use a systemd service with a respawn option.